# How to create Plots with Julia from a Docker image?

Tags: docker, plot, julia

it seems given you just got Julia app from the image, you need some  dependencies to create plots. Any idea how to work this around.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is on how to do the plotting without a GUI backend. In that case you can just plot to a PDF file:

```
using Plots  

ENV["GKSwstype"]="nul"                  
                                     
p=plot(sin.(1:0.5:10));       
                                     
savefig(p, "plot.pdf")
```

You should be able to install `Plots.jl` just like any other Julia package in your docker container.

Comment: got this message: qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
connect: Connection refused
GKS: can't connect to GKS socket application

GKS: Open failed in routine OPEN_WS
GKS: GKS not in proper state. GKS must be either in the state WSOP or WSAC in routine ACTIVATE_WS

Comment: Please try `ENV["GKSwstype"]="nul" ` before calling `plot`. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: yes. It worked. It created the file. Now, I'll look for bridging the container or look for a more functional solution.